# jOOQ Subquery in Order By

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I'm using a subquery in order by like this on MySQL 8 database:

```
select * from series 
order by (select max(competition.competition_date) from competition 
          where competition.series_id = series.id) desc
```

But I didn't find a way to do that with jOOQ.

I tried the following query but this does not compile:

```
dsl
   .selectFrom(SERIES)
   .orderBy(dsl.select(DSL.max(COMPETITION.COMPETITION_DATE))
               .from(COMPETITION).where(COMPETITION.SERIES_ID.eq(SERIES.ID)).desc())
   .fetch()
```

Are subqueries not supported in order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the subquery into a Field works:

```
dsl.selectFrom(SERIES)
   .orderBy(DSL.field(dsl.select(DSL.max(COMPETITION.COMPETITION_DATE)).from(COMPETITION)
                  .where(COMPETITION.SERIES_ID.eq(SERIES.ID))).desc())
   .fetch()
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `Select<R> extends Field<R>`

There's a pending feature request [#4828](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4828) to let `Select<R> extend Field<R>`. This seems tempting because jOOQ already supports nested records to some extent for those dialects that support it.

But I have some doubts whether this is really a good idea in this case, because no database I'm aware of (i.e. where I tried this) supports scalar subqueries that project more than one column. It's possible to use such subqueries in row value expression predicates, e.g.

```sql
(a, b) IN (SELECT x, y FROM t)
```

But that's a different story, because it's limited to predicates, and not arbitrary column expressions. And it is already supported in jOOQ, via the various [`DSL.row()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#row(org.jooq.Field,org.jooq.Field)) overloads, e.g.

```java
row(A, B).in(select(T.X, T.Y).from(T))
```

#### `Select<Record1<T>> extends Field<T>`

This is definitely desireable, because a `SELECT` statement that projects only one column of type `T` really *is* a `Field<T>` in SQL, i.e. a scalar subquery. But letting `Select<Record1<T>>` extend `Field<T>` is not possible in Java. There is no way to express this using Java's generics. If we wanted to do this, we'd have to "overload" the `Select` type itself and create

- `Select1<T1> extends Select<Record1<T1>>`
- `Select2<T1, T2> extends Select<Record2<T1, T2>>`
- etc.

In that case, `Select1<T1>` could be a special case, extending `Field<T1>`, and the other ones would not participate in such a type hierarchy. But in order to achieve this, we'd have to duplicate the entire `Select` DSL API *per projection degree*, i.e. copy it 22 times, which is probably not worth it. There are already [67 `Select.*Step` types in the jOOQ API](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/package-summary.html), as of jOOQ 3.13. This makes it difficult to justify the enhancement even only for scalar subqueries, i.e. for `Select1`.

#### Using [`DSL.field(Select<Record1<T>>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field(org.jooq.Select)) and related API

[You've already found the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61526221/521799). While `Select<Record1<T>>` cannot extend `Field<T>`, we can accept `Select<? extends Record1<T>>` in plenty of API, as an overload to the usual `T|Field<T>` overloads. This has been done occasionally, and might be done more thoroughly throughout the API: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7240.

It wouldn't help you, because you want to call `.desc()` on a column expression (the `Select`), rather than wrap pass it to a method, so we're back at Java's limitation mentioned before.

#### Kotlin and other languages

If you're using Kotlin or other languages that have some way of providing "extension functions", however, you could use this approach:

```kotlin
inline fun <T> Select<Record1<T>>.desc(): SortField<T> {
    return DSL.field(this).desc();
}
```

jOOQ might provide these out of the box in the future: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6256

Comment: Thanks for the for the background